# Binary compatibility libraries same compiler and compiler version, different OS version

Tags: c++, abi, binary-compatibility

I have a question regarding binary compatibility.

Suppose I build a library/executable using GCC 9.x for Ubuntu 22.04. I now want to use these binaries also on Ubuntu 23.10.
Assuming I didn't accidentally statically link in system libraries, am I able to run/use these binaries for the newer OS? Under the assumption that I link them to the correct libglibc.so etc.

I have tried doing this locally, and it did seem to work. I however have no clue if that is by accident, or is actually reasonable.

Comment: You can use ldd command to check if any missing library for your executable

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So you mean that if `ldd` doesn't complain about missing libraries, everything should be alright? No weird runtime errors because of incompatibilties?

Comment: With my knowledge I can say that